# Python 3 get depth of current list loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I need to loop through nested lists of unknown depth and get the paths as well as the variables. I can loop through the lists and get the variables just fine but I can't figure out how to get the path because theres only one for loop for all of the loops. If I could get the depth the code is currently looping through then I could tell the program which part of the path(savelist) should be changed.

If there is another way to loop through arbitarily nested lists and get the path as well as the variables then feel free to mention it. If that happens then I'll try changing the name of the question.

Note also that I can't search for the item in the list because there might be duplicates and I want to access all information inside the list. There's also an added complication in that the solution will need to be easily adjusted to work with dictionaries and lists nested together.

This is my code...(I get that calling the functions this way will eventually cause it to crash but I'm not concerned with that right now.)

```
global savelist
savelist=[]

def for1(var):
    global savelist
    for f in range(len(var)):
        if isinstance(var[f], list):
            savelist.append(f)
            loop(var[f])
        if isinstance(var[f], str):
            savelist.append(f)
            savelist.append(var[f])
            print(savelist)
            savelist.pop()
            savelist.pop()

def loop(var):
    for1(var)

def main():
    loop(foods)

main()
```

It is supposed to take this list

```
foods=["avacado"
       , ["lemon", "orange", "lime"]
       , [["crabapple", "apple"], ["wild pear", "pear"]] 
       , [["ham", "bacon"], ["steak", "brisket"], ["tilapia", "cod"]]
]
```

and output this

```
[0, 'avacado']
[1, 0, 'lemon']
[1, 1, 'orange']
[1, 2, 'lime']
[2, 0, 0, 'crabapple']
[2, 0, 1, 'apple']
[2, 1, 0, 'wild pear']
[2, 1, 1, 'pear']
[3, 0, 0, 'ham']
[3, 0, 1, 'bacon']
[3, 1, 0, 'steak']
[3, 1, 1, 'brisket']
[3, 2, 0, 'tilapia']
[3, 2, 1, 'cod']
```

but instead it outputs this

```
[0, 'avacado']
[1, 0, 'lemon']
[1, 1, 'orange']
[1, 2, 'lime']
[1, 2, 0, 0, 'crabapple']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 'apple']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 'wild pear']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 'pear']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 'ham']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 'bacon']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 'steak']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 'brisket']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 'tilapia']
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 'cod']
```

If I could tell which depth I'm in inside of the for loop then I could edit the correct savelist number. As it is I lack that information and I can't find an easy way to work around that.

Comment: As a side note, because you are only calling member functions of a mutable object, `savelist` does not need to be declared `global`.

Comment: is it required that you need to do this with only one loop?

Comment: @Tomothy32 That is left over from previous versions of my code where it started complaining about savelist being undefined despite it being defined above the functions. Your right though, it's now completely unnessisary, should I edit the question?

Comment: @silverwind No edit is needed, I just wanted to point it out in case you weren't aware of it. It doesn't really affect the question.

Comment: @Tom There can be as many loops as needed but I don't know how deeply nested the lists are going to be. The example list is just to test whether the code works, the lists and things I'm going to be using this on will be more deeply nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put what you are doing into words. It seemed to me that you wanted a list of indices for each string. So pass the list and the current indices to a recursive function.

```
foods=["avacado"
       , ["lemon", "orange", "lime"]
       , [["crabapple", "apple"], ["wild pear", "pear"]]
       , [["ham", "bacon"], ["steak", "brisket"], ["tilapia", "cod"]]
]

def homework(lst, indices):
  ret = []
  if isinstance(lst, str):
    ret.append( indices + [lst] )
    return ret
  for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    ret.extend( homework(x, indices + [i]) )
  return ret

print ( homework(foods,[]) )
```

Comment: This works perfectly and can easily be changed to work with more types. I will probably mark this as the answer but could you explain how exactly this works?

Comment: Maybe sam46 or another can explain his better, but I already put my explanation in the answer.  We want a list of indices for each string so just return indices + [str].  Once you state out loud what you want to do it is simple.  Lookup enumerate and extend then play around if you are unfamiliar how they work.

Answer (score 3):

For this sort of recursion, a generator often works well:

#### Code

```
def dump(levels, foods):
    for i, food in enumerate(foods):
        if isinstance(food, list):
            yield from dump(levels + [i], food)
        else:
            yield levels + [i, food]
```

#### Test Code:

```
foods = [
    "avacado",
    ["lemon", "orange", "lime"],
    [
        ["crabapple", "apple"], ["wild pear", "pear"]
    ], [
        ["ham", "bacon"], ["steak", "brisket"], ["tilapia", "cod"]
    ]
]

for i in dump([], foods):
    print(i)
```

#### Results:

```
[0, 'avacado']
[1, 0, 'lemon']
[1, 1, 'orange']
[1, 2, 'lime']
[2, 0, 0, 'crabapple']
[2, 0, 1, 'apple']
[2, 1, 0, 'wild pear']
[2, 1, 1, 'pear']
[3, 0, 0, 'ham']
[3, 0, 1, 'bacon']
[3, 1, 0, 'steak']
[3, 1, 1, 'brisket']
[3, 2, 0, 'tilapia']
[3, 2, 1, 'cod']
```

Comment: I like the generator